Apache VFS2 SFTP "Could not connect to SFTP server"
I have a really old Java program that makes SFTP connections to an external server. This program used the VFS library (version 1.0).
Everything worked perfectly until the external server disabled some encryption algorithms. My program was affected and the SFTP connection no longer worked at all.
The server authorizes a list of key exchange algorithms like "curve25519-sha256" or "curve25519-sha256@libssh.org" or "diffie-hellman-group18-sha512" or "diffie-hellman-group17-sha512" or "diffie-hellman-group16-sha512" or "diffie-hellman-group15-sha512" or "diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256, ...
The server is supposed to allow the “aes256-ctr” and “aes256-gcm@openssh.com” encryption algorithms.
I saw that with VFS2 it was possible to change the key exchange algorithm, so I installed VFS2 instead of VFS and was able to configure the algorithm in the SFTP options:
FileSystemOptions sftpOptions = new FileSystemOptions();
SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder sftpFileSystemConfigBuilder = SftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.getInstance();
sftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.setCompression(sftpOptions, "zlib,none");
sftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.setKnownHosts(sftpOptions, new File(configuration.getKnownHostsFile()));
sftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.setStrictHostKeyChecking(sftpOptions, "yes");
sftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.setKeyExchangeAlgorithm(sftpOptions, "diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256");
UserInfo userInfo = new KeyPairUserInfo(configuration.getPassPhrase());
sftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.setUserInfo(sftpOptions, userInfo);
File[] identities = { new File(configuration.getIdentityFile()) };
sftpFileSystemConfigBuilder.setIdentities(sftpOptions, identities);

When I tested the new code, I got the following logs:
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) Connecting to xxx port 22
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) Connection established
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) Remote version string: SSH-2.0-""
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.52
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) aes256-ctr is not available.
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) aes192-ctr is not available.
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) aes256-cbc is not available.
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) aes192-cbc is not available.
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) kex: server: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group17-sha512,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group15-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ext-info-s
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) kex: server: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) kex: server: aes256-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-ctr
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) kex: server: aes256-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-ctr
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) kex: server: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) kex: server: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) kex: server: none,zlib
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) kex: server: none,zlib
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) kex: server: 
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) kex: server: 
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) kex: client: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) kex: client: zlib,none
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) kex: client: zlib,none
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) kex: client: 
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) kex: client: 
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (EJB default - 1) Disconnecting from xxx port 22

ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (EJB default - 1) WFLYEJB0020: Error invoking timeout for timer: javax.ejb.EJBException: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp://xxxx@xxxx/".
[...] 
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp://xxxx@xxxx/".
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.createSession(SftpFileProvider.java:73)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:94)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.getFileSystem(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:93)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:72)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:56)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:716)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:653)
... 67 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "xxx".
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:163)
at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.createSession(SftpFileProvider.java:66)
... 74 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.receive_kexinit(Session.java:583)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:320)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:161)
... 75 more

I can't figure out why the connection fails.
I can't understand why it says “aes256-ctr is not available.” Is the problem with the server or the client?

server: aes256-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-ctr vs client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc. Or in other words, the problem is with the client (or at least, there being no overlap between the client and server).

It took me a while, but I finally solved the connection problem.
I did a lot of research and tried out a number of online solutions.
The one that worked was the following:

Locate the Java installation path

In my case, it was “C:\Program FilesJava\jdk1.8.0_102”.

Download the file “jce_policy-8.zip”

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce8-downloads.html

Unzip the file and, in the Java installation folder, make a backup and replace the files named “local_policy.jar” and “US_export_policy.jar”.

In my case, the path to the files is “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre\lib\security”
WARNING: if several versions of Java exist, you must modify the files for the correct version. Otherwise, it won't work.
Here are the logs now:
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) Connecting to xxxx port 22
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) Connection established
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) Remote version string: SSH-2.0-""
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.52
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) CheckSignatures: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: server: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group17-sha512,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group15-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ext-info-s
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: server: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: server: aes256-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-ctr
2024-08-30 14:26:49,594 INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: server: aes256-ctr,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes192-ctr
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: server: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: server: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: server: none,zlib
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: server: none,zlib
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: server: 
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: server: 
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: client: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-ctr,aes192-cbc,aes256-ctr,aes256-cbc
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: client: zlib,none
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: client: zlib,none
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: client: 
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: client: 
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: server->client aes192-ctr hmac-sha1 zlib
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) kex: client->server aes192-ctr hmac-sha1 zlib
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<1024) sent
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) expecting SSH_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) Host 'xxxx' is known and matches the RSA host key
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) Next authentication method: publickey
INFO  [org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory] (default task-16) Authentication succeeded (publickey).

The connection now seems to be working!
I'm having problems retrieving files from the server but it seems to be coming from something else.
Thanks for the help!

Why are you still using Java 8 update 102 (July 2016)?! The current latest version of Java 8 is Java 8 update 421/422 (depending on the vendor), you are several years of updates behind (including security issues). If you had used a recent Java 8 version, you'd never had this problem, because since Java 8 update 161 (January 2018), the unlimited strength cryptography policy is the default.
